# How to get Dreamweaver to recognize SASS files, with color coding

Tags: sass, dreamweaver

I'm trying to get my SASS files to open in Dreamweaver, and for it to be color coded, but I'm having a little problem.

First, what I have done:

I've updated the extensions file found under  ~username –> Library –> Application Support –> Adobe –> Dreamweaver CS6 (or whatever version you have) –> en_us –> Configuration –> Extensions.txt to read CSS,SCSS,LESS:Style Sheets.

I've also updated the MMDocumentTypes.xml to winfileextension=”scss,less,css” macfileextension=”scss,less,css”.

Dreamweaver will still not open scss files via File>Open, but will open the file if I drag the scss file onto the dreamweaver icon. However, after doing this, the file is not color coded. Is there something I'm missing?